# ¿Como indicar si es mayor de edad y devolver en booleano?

Tags: java, netbeans

```
public boolean es_MAYOR_de_Edad()
{
 if (Edad<=17) // Utilizo condicionales
 if else (Edad>=18) //Por ejemplo para mayor    

 return ¿?;

}
```

Comment: Debido a que es una expresión booleana, se puede reducir a `return Edad >= 18`, retornará `true` si es mayor o igual a 18, `false` en caso de que sea menor a 18.

Comment: Necesitas ser mas especifico en tus preguntas.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar el siguiente código:

```
public boolean esMayorDeEdad(int edad) {
    return edad >= 18;
}
```

Debes tener en consideración algunas cosas:

1. El estandar de codificación de Java es lowerCamelCase para propiedades y métodos.
2. Para hacer la operación tu método debe recibir un parámetro y poder evaluar con propiedad.

El código que te puse de ejemplo resuelve la condición de la siguiente forma:

"edad es mayor a 18" si? regresa true, no? regresa false.

Que solo para este ejemplo, semánticamente, es lo mismo que tenerlo de la forma

```
public boolean esMayorDeEdad(int edad) {
     if (edad >= 18) {
        return true;
     } else {
        return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: como tu mismo le recomiendas, si debe elaborar una buena pregunta, entonces aún no debías responder hasta que la mejore el OP

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, @shadow, pero antes que desalentar su participación prefiero a que aprenda con "refuerzos positivos"

Comment: nadie lo esta desalentando, pero es mejor dejarle comentarios de que debe hacer para recibir ayuda

Comment: Vale, lo tendré en cuenta la próxima ocasión

Comment: [Te podrían votar negativamente porque no esperaste a entender la pregunta antes de contestar.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3217/342)